# Stucked at the very last step for proving additive function over the reals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm stucked at the very last step to prove that for any additive function over the reals, $f(x)=kx$. [This is a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235150/given-that-f-is-additive-and-f-is-continous-at-0-prove-fx-kx-where-k-f1), but I don't understand how to fit continuity with the fact that $x$ is any real. (I have proven that $f(r)=kr$ for $r$ rational).

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$, this implies for any $x$ real, there exists a sequence of rationals $r_n$ such that $r_n\to x$. Use the fact that a continuous function is sequentially continuous

Comment: There also  exist discontinuous additive  $h:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R.$ Such  $h$ are "very discontinuous" in that $\{h(x):x\in (a,b)\}=\Bbb R$ whenever $a<b.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-kx$. Then $g(x)=0$ when $x\in\mathbb Q$. Since $f$ (and, therefore, $g$) is continuous, if $x\in\mathbb R$, you take a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=x$ and then$$g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.$$